# How to remove class the close the sub menus when some other link is clicked

Tags: angular

menu-open and active class are added when user clicks on the menu which has a submenu.

I am trying to remove those two classes and close the sub menu when the user clicks on another like for example My Profile route here

```
<li class="treeview" routerLinkActive="li-bg" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
    <a routerLink="/dashboard/my-profile">
      <i class="fa fa-user ic"></i><span class="d-title">My Profile</span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <!-- admin -->
  <li *ngIf="isAdmin" [ngClass]="{'li-bg':adminLinkHighlight()}"
  #myLi class="treeview" (click)="myLi.classList.toggle('menu-open'); myLi.classList.toggle('active');">
      <a style="cursor: pointer;">
          <i class="fa fa fa-shield ic"></i> <span class="d-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;Admin Options</span>
          <span class="pull-right-container">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
          </span>
      </a>
        <!-- <ul class="treeview-menu"> -->
        <ul (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" class="treeview-menu">
            <li style="cursor: pointer;"><a routerLink="/dashboard/files">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Files</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" class="treeview-menu">
          <li style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="navigatToUsers();"><a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Users</a></li>
      </ul>

</li>
```

Comment: use like this <a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="acitve" class="nav-link">Home</a> reference link : https://www.truecodex.com/course/angular-project-training/create-routing-navigation-and-inner-page-angular

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem with @Hostlistener. Below is my personal reference code and here is the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hostlistener-dom-traversal?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts)

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    // event contains all methods and DOM objects of the clicked element
    console.log(event);

    // event.target returns the node that was targeted by the function. 
    // This means you can work with the node like one you'd get from document.getElementById
    console.log(event.target);

    // Using target’s methods sometimes require typing the targetted element: 
    // `(<ElementType>event.target).METHOD`
    console.log((<HTMLElement>event.target).querySelector('input'));// TS error
    console.log((<HTMLElement>event.target).querySelector('p')); // TS works

    // get a node list of all elements with .class-name
    console.log(this.eRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.class-name'));


    // 1. log clicking any elements within a parent component from this child component
    // 2. log clicking anywhere outside the parent component
    if (this.eRef.nativeElement.parentNode.contains(event.target)) {
      this.area = 'Clicked any element within parent component: (' + (<HTMLElement>event.target).tagName + ')';
    } else if(!this.eRef.nativeElement.parentNode.contains(event.target)) {
      this.area = 'Clicked outside parent component: (' + (<HTMLElement>event.target).tagName + ')';
    } else {
      this.area = 'Clicked parent component: (' + (<HTMLElement>event.target).tagName + ')';
    }
}
```

You can use a `@Hostlistener` in a Component, Directive or Pipe.

Add and remove classes properly with `Renderer2`

```
renderer.addClass(hostElement.nativeElement, 'class-name');

renderer.removeClass(hostElement.nativeElement, 'class-name');
```